# Populate a dropdown with entity database via ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, entity-framework, model-view-controller

As the title says, I'm trying to use ajax to populate a dropdown list from my ApiController and I'm a bit lost. I basically have an entity table that brings back a bunch of department names. After debugging, I know my table is bringing back data as it shows department names coming through. So I think the issue mainly lies within the ajax. When I view the page, the dropdown just says 'nothing selected' and has an empty list. In my ApiController I have:

```
    [RoutePrefix("Api/Request")]
    public class NewUserController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ZeusEntities _zeus_Entity;

        public NewUserController(ZeusEntities zeus)
        {
            _zeus_Entity = zeus;
        }

        [Route("Departments")]
        [HttpGet]
        [CustomApiAuthorize(Roles = UserRole.HR)]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDepartments()
        {
            var departments = await _zeus_Entity.DEPARTMENT.Where(z => z.B_DELETE == 0).Select(z => z.S_NAME).Distinct().ToListAsync();

            return Ok(departments);
        }
     }
```

And in my view, I have:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
     <div class="input-group ">
          <span class="input-group-addon white">Department</span>
          <select class="form-control gray" id="departmentSelect" type="text" </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Inline:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("Departments", "Api/Request")",
    data: "{}",
    success: function (data) {
        var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Department</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            s += '<option value="' + data[i].I_PATTERNID + '">' + data[i].S_NAME + '</option>';
        }
        $("#departmentSelect").html(s);
    }
});
```

Could you please point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Print and see what does `data` has . Also , are you returning json response ? If yes you need parse that before accessing .

Comment: @Swati would it be best to return a json response? After running I can check in chrome dev tools and see that GetDepartments is getting the correct data, however the list just shows 'undefined' as all the options.

Comment: Parse your json i.e :  `JSON.parse(data)` then access that values see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I change the ajax for function to a $.each and realized that I was calling the table column names instead of the variable names I assigned to the data.

```
$.each(deptList, function (key, department) {
       departmentsHtml += "<option value='" + department.DeptId + "'>" + department.Department + "</option>"
 });
```

I feel very silly that I overlooked that bit. Nonetheless, that solved my issue.